# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '[field]' to data type int

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm creating a smart list for better viewing of reports.

My problem is when im generating the query below, it fails with this error message "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Field2' to data type int."

This my query

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [SECCODE]) AS RowNumber 
FROM myDB.mySchema.myView 
WHERE [Field1]<[Field2]) tempTable WHERE [tempTable].[RowNumber]>=1 AND [tempTable].[RowNumber]<=100
```

The Field2 is from a textbox. I try to put the exact field name but I still get the error.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @v1 varchar(20);

select cast(@v1 as int)..


SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [SECCODE]) AS RowNumber 
FROM myDB.mySchema.myView 
WHERE [Field1]<cast([Field2] as int) tempTable WHERE [tempTable].[RowNumber]>=1 AND [tempTable].[RowNumber]<=100
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `cast` or `convert`?

`cast(varcharColumn as Int)` or `CONVERT(INT, varcharColumn)`